# Postgres password change issues

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Everything was working fine until I decided to change the Postgres password.

Now I am able to login to Postgres from PgAdmin, but my Laravel project is not running.
I changed the password in the'.env' file and tried to clear the cache as well. I don't know if I am missing anything important.

Error:
[image]

I am using Postgres 12 and Laravel 6.

Comment: try running php artisan optimize:clear

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a user and make access to the database for that user.
you can follow these steps and run these queries on PgAdmin.

-- Create ROLE

```
CREATE ROLE {username} WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '{password}';
enter code hereALTER ROLE {username} CREATEDB;
```

-- CREATE DATABASE

```
CREATE DATABASE {database};
```

-- Make access for your new user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database TO 
{username};
```

Comment: Actually, I only wanted to change the password for existing user say 'postgres'. Do i have to grant privileges again?

Comment: I'm not sure but your error is related to one of these problems.
1) your user doesn't grant to the database.
2) your user doesn't have a role to do it.
then I think if you can try it we can understand the problem well.